# How can I say "I think the Eastern culture is much wiser than Western culture"?

Tags: translation

How can I say "I think the Eastern culture is much wiser than Western culture"?

I've tried "我想东文化比西文化很明智的", but Google is translating this as "I think the Eastern culture is very wise" (!!)

I'm in doubt if I should use a 是, or if I could drop the final 的. Like "我想东文化是比西文化很明智". If 的 is necessary, what's exactly its function in the sentence?

Comment: 很 not used in comparisons,why not 
东方文化比西方文化明智多了／得多

Comment: What does Google say if you drop 很 or drop 的, or both?

Comment: @user6065 Both 我想东文化比西文化明智很多 and 我想东文化比西文化明智得多 work. Thank you!

Comment: @ColinMcLarty If I drop the 很, I lose the "much". If I drop the 的, I get "I think the East culture is very wise than the West culture". If I drop both, "I think the Eastern culture is more wise than the West culture", no "much" again.

Comment: feeding 东文化 to jukuu: 0 results, feeding 东方文化 ７２ results of which first 34 contain the unbroken sequence

Comment: @user6065 Great addition! Please add both comments as an answer?

Comment: @user6065 Also thanks for introducing me to http://www.jukuu.com!

Comment: @Rodrigo Are you using Google Translate?  Those are not what mine gives me for those. And did you not just ask it how to say what you want?

Comment: @ColinMcLarty Yes, Google Translate. I think the translation varies from person to person, probably as a reflect of all the engineering Google does with AdSearch, etc. Also I don't think its translation to Chinese is so good, I only use it as an approximation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Eastern culture is much wiser than Western culture

Translation：

"I think" can be translated as 我认为 我的想法是 我觉得 我的观点是 etc

“much wiser than” can be translated as 比XX更聪明 比XX更有智慧 比XX聪明的多 etc

In conclusion:

1、我认为东方文化比西方文化更高明。

2、我觉得东方文化比西方文化更有智慧。

3、我认为，相比西方文化，东方文化更有智慧。

Comment: Thank you! 我想 is wrong? Or is it just less used? Maybe too informal? And what about 明智 for wise?

Comment: less used in this context,想 has many other meanings :bkrs：想to think
to believe
to suppose
to wish
to want
to miss (feel wistful about the absence of sb or sth)
xiǎng
think, speculate, plan, consider
1) 开动脑筋：思索；想办法｜想方设法。
2) 推测；认为：我想他今天不会来。
3) 希望；打算：我想到杭州去一趟。
1) 怀念；想念：想家｜我们很想你。jukuu：a. desirous

v. think wish feel suppose believe hold expect consider
  
想 also used as modal verb (能愿动词）表示＂愿望＂、＂打算＂examples for 想／think：What were these people thinking?
 这些人在怎么想呢？feed ＂想 think＂ to jukuu to get 100 examples,

Comment: My Chinese teacher liked specially number 2. I'll use it. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

不需要加“是”字，还有，明智在这里很拗口，用楼上的“智慧”是个不错的选择

Answer (score -3):

I think this sentence ought to give people an accurate impression of the situation:

我认为中国人崇洋拜外比不上西方人搞东方主义。

Comment: What exactly do you mean? What's the English translation of your Chinese sentence?

Comment: @Rodrigo, might I suggest you familiarize yourself with the concepts of "cultural essentialism" and "orientalism"?

Comment: Yes, you may. But you may better yet speak clearly and to the point?

Comment: I know what cultural essentialism is. But to deny the main differences between both cultures is very shallow. Have you studied anything of Eastern philosophy? Have you seen my argument with Tang Ho above? Or are you one of those who say something and run, pretending you have won the argument?

Comment: -1 since you don't want to answer the questions that would make your thoughts more clear.

Comment: Your behavior is a perfect illustration to my sentence.

Comment: Scram answer. Lol. You clearly know the proper meaning. But I'm confused about the "orientalism in the western world" part. From my personal experience, western people(US) seems don't value eastern culture as much as Eastern Asia people(mainly China)value western culture.

Comment: @Kevman In the west, it's common for certain people (often on the left) to criticize western culture (often fairly) and to fetishize eastern culture as being 1. mystical and 2. free of whatever problems they attribute to western culture. It's pretty eye-roll inducing. This is common enough that just the other day I saw a [parody of this behavior](http://www.theonion.com/article/tibetan-teen-getting-into-western-philosophy-4782) where the roles of east and west are flipped.

Comment: @StumpyJoePete I believe this phenomenon could be track back to Enlightenment Era due to the background of the world at that time. Even though being treated as so called "yellow fever" is better than "yellow peril", it sounds ridiculous to me.